# SPRING MVC data and password validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have two fields time in and time out I want to validate the time out so it will not accept a value less than the value of time in ex the time in is 9:15 the time out shouldn't accept a value of 9:00 or less

```
@Column(name="timein")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
    @NotBlank
    private Date timeIn;

    @Column(name="timeout")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
    @NotBlank
    private Date timeOut;
```

And one more is for the confirm password field how can I validate that the two match?

```
@NotBlank
  private String password;

  @NotBlank 
  private String confirmPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement Validator and add a validate method that verifies what you want.  Call the validate method from your submit method.